# Magento 1.9.4.1 unable to add logs Mage::log() issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I have installed Magento 1.9.4.1 When I tried to add logs, log files not creating.

I just want to ask is it a new feature of an updated version or is there any patches available for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this commit is all you are looking for:

https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/0596cae2d25bf467edbd3d3f03ab9f8f

Comment: "-1" b/c i'm pretty sure this comes from another question/answer you know ;) Next time, please flag at least as dupe **too**.

Comment: I did mark it as duplicate ;) I think I was the first to mark it :P but okey, was only trying to help :p

Comment: I didnt downvote, and have not seen your dupe flag. sorry. :)

Comment: It's fine. To be fair, I am not sure what to do in situations like this. The question/answer I got this info from has lots of answers and ot could be difficult for the OP to find what they are looking for. Although, this question is more specific and could be answered with part of the duplicated question... you think providing an answer and marking as duplicate is a good approach?

Comment: Generally it is a good approach. What I do is ... if i find/know a another same question, i just mark it is a dupe. If I've time to checkthe answers and find one that i'd recommend I maybe copy it as answer and link to source & and +1 for the author there. I also downvote the question b/c if they are below "0" and unanswered within 30 days, they will be deleted. (just to keep it clean). But the most important point - IMHO - is to flag as dupe - just to point other to the right quesetion/direction :)